# VBA how to copy the formula and formatting of a cell quickly?

Tags: vba, excel

[Latest finding] I found that `value(11)` can actually copy **formulas** sometimes, but not always. Formulas like `sumproduct` and `sumif` cannot be copied, but simple arithmetic operations can be copied. This is so strange! I still cannot figure out why.

I know that if I want to copy values only, the fastest way is

```
Range("A1").Value = Range("A2").Value
```

If I want to copy formatting and values, the fastest way is

```
Range("A1").Value(11) = Range("A2").Value(11)
```

If I want to copy formulas, the fastest way is

```
Range("A1").Formula = Range("A2").Formula
```

What if I want to copy both the formula and formatting? (I have many formatting in that cell, like conditional formatting, bold, underline, alignment, number display format, border style, etc., so it is not practical to transfer each of the styles one at a time.)

Comment: There isn't much wrong with copy&paste if you can do it in bulk, rather than cell by cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out a simple answer.

```
Range("A1").Value(11) = Range("A2").Value(11)
Range("A1").Formula = Range("A2").Formula
```

Since `value(11)` fails when copying some complicated formulas (I don't know why, should be a bug in Excel), I added the second line to paste the formula again. This should ensure all formulas are copied correctly.

Comment: One word of caution: the .formula = .formula converts any numbers that have an apostrophe preceding it (some users do this so the sheet shows a number but it's not included in formulas) back in to a number and strips the apostrophe. The value(11) works fine but as soon as the .formula is run, any numbers that you want to be excluded in formulas suddenly are. Work around is to wrap numbers in brackets [ ]. It shows as a number but isn't included in formulas. Wish Microsoft would just fix the bug with the .value(11) to copy over all formulas...

Answer (score 2):

To copy formulas with the formatting in the source range and keep the formulas relative (e.g. like using Ctr-C and Ctr-V) use this copy and paste method:

```
Range("A1").Copy Range("A2")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a sub like this:

```
Sub copyFormattingAndFormulas(source As Range, target As Range)

    Dim sourceCell, targetCell As Range
    Dim i, j, lastRow, lastColumn As Integer
    lastRow = source.rows.count + source.row - 1
    lastColumn = source.columns.count + source.Column - 1
    For i = source.row To lastRow
        For j = source.Column To lastColumn
            Set sourceCell = Cells(source.row + i - 1, source.Column + j - 1)
            Set targetCell = Cells(target.row + i - 1, target.Column + j - 1)
            targetCell.value(11) = sourceCell.value(11)
            targetCell = sourceCell.Formula
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

All it does is do both the things you showed in the question (good to know about .value(11)!) in a loop for a specified range.